# Sprite Sheet animation fails after upgrading from Cocos2d 1.0.1 to 2.0

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, ccsprite

I created a simple, 2 frame sprite animation based off a few tutorials that I found across the web. I took my 2 images, created a sprite sheet with plist and png file, and incorporated them into my code as seen below. This setup worked fine in Cocos2d V 1.0.1. I just upgraded my project to 2.0rc0a and now my app crashes with the following error at the point where it should switch from the first frame to the second: `'CCSprite: setTexture doesn't work when the sprite is rendered using a CCSpriteBatchNode'`

I looked at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9305286/1007725), but I'm not sure if it's the same thing that I'm doing wrong, and because I'm still very new to Cocos2d, am unsure how to correctly adjust my code. Is this something that was changed in 2.0 that I didn't see in the notes, a bug that I should report, or just incorrect coding on my part? I still have a copy of the 1.0.1 project with identical code and the animation works correctly.

```
//CHAMELEON
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"front page/mainchameleon.plist"];
mainChameleon = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"front page/mainchameleon.png"];
[self addChild:mainChameleon z:7];
NSMutableArray *chameleonFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) 
{
    [chameleonFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"chameleon%d.png", i]]];
}

CCAnimation *mouthAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:chameleonFrames delay:0.3f];
chameleon = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"chameleon1.png"];
CCAnimate *chameleonAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:mouthAnim];
CCDelayTime *chameleonDelay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:10];
CCRepeatForever *chameleonRepeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:chameleonDelay, chameleonAction, chameleonDelay, nil]]; 
[chameleon runAction:chameleonRepeat];
[mainChameleon addChild:chameleon];
```

If I comment out `chameleon = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"chameleon1.png"];` then the app doesn't crash, but the chameleon doesn't appear at all, as would be expected with how the code is currently written.

Or, if I comment out `[chameleon runAction:chameleonRepeat];` then the chameleon appears showing the frame, chameleon1.png, but obviously doesn't go through the animation.

OK, so to make me even more confused because I'm definitely missing something, I tried changing the bottom portion of the code to this and the animation goes from frame 1, to frame 2, then stays on 2 indefinitely. However, if I make the delay anything longer than 1.0, I receive the same error I was getting before. If I re-include `chameleonDelay` prior to the action without the repeat forever statement, I also get the same crash. It appears that the app crashes if it has to wait longer than 1 second to perform the switch. What I need is for frame 1 to sit for a while (10 seconds) then switch to frame 2 for 0.3 seconds, then switch back to frame 1 and sit for a while again.

Attempted code #2:

```
CCAnimation *mouthAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:chameleonFrames delay:0.3f]; //<--- maxes out at 1.0. Anything more causes crash
chameleon = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"chameleon1.png"];
CCAnimate *chameleonAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:mouthAnim];     
[chameleon runAction:chameleonAction];
[mainChameleon addChild:chameleon];
```

YvesLeBorg suggested using the restoreOriginalFrame statement, but that is deprecated in ver 2.0. I tried using

`CCAnimation *mouthAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithAnimationFrames:chameleonFrames delayPerUnit:0.3f loops:5];`

and get the error `'-[CCSpriteFrame delayUnits]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'`. I'm not sure why that isn't working or what else to try from here.

**EDIT: So Now It's Working...But not as efficiently coded as I'd like:**

New Code:

```
//CHAMELEON
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"front page/mainchameleon.plist"];
mainChameleon = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"front page/mainchameleon.png"];
[self addChild:mainChameleon z:7];
NSMutableArray *chameleonFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

//Frame 1 - closed mouth
[chameleonFrames addObject:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:mainChameleon.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 124, 149, 122)]];
//Frame 2 - Open Mouth
[chameleonFrames addObject:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:mainChameleon.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 149, 122)]];
//Frame 1 - closed mouth
[chameleonFrames addObject:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:mainChameleon.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 124, 149, 122)]];

CCAnimation *mouthAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:chameleonFrames delay:0.9f];
    chameleon = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:mainChameleon.texture rect:CGRectMake(0,124,149,122)];
CCAnimate *chameleonAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:mouthAnim];
CCDelayTime *chameleonDelay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:10];
CCRepeatForever *chameleonRepeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:chameleonDelay, chameleonAction, nil]]; 
[chameleon runAction:chameleonRepeat];
[mainChameleon addChild:chameleon];
```

I really liked the way that I was doing it in 1.0.1 because if I had 2 frames or 100 frames, I only had to make a small adjustment to the if statement. This way requires coding each individual frame which seems counter-intuitive to using a plist. If no one is able to provide a better solution, or "real" answer in the next few days, I will post this as an answer and accept it to close out the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up with that works correctly. Not sure why I had to make these changes, but there it is. (Some of the names have changed as I started a new project to fix this on, but the differences between my original code and this are apparent). To anyone else finding this thread, my original code was based on [Ray Wenderlich's sprite sheet tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d).

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *chameleonBN = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"chameleonimages.png"];
    [self addChild:chameleonBN];

//ADDED the texture part to resolve: 'CCSprite: setTexture doesn't work when the sprite is rendered using a CCSpriteBatchNode'   
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"chameleonplist.plist" texture:chameleonBN.texture];

NSMutableArray *chameleonframes = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 1; i <= 2 ; i++) 
{
    [chameleonframes addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"chameleon%d.png", i]]];
}

CCAnimation *mouthAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:chameleonframes delay:0.9f];

//ADDED this sprite frame to resolve texture id assert error
CCSpriteFrame *frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:chameleonBN.texture rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 149, 122)];
CCSprite *chameleon = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
chameleon.position = ccp(512,384);
CCAnimate *chameleonAnimate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:mouthAnim];

CCDelayTime *chameleonDelay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:10];
CCDelayTime *chameleonDelay2 = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.1];//Had to use this to ge tthe mouth to close. Using restore original frame doesn't work for me.
CCRepeatForever *chameleonRepeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:chameleonDelay, chameleonAnimate, chameleonDelay2, nil]]; 
[chameleon runAction:chameleonRepeat];
[chameleonBN addChild:chameleon];
```

Comment: Hello there. First of all thanks for the detailed question + answer. I stumbled upon the same problem today, but I solved it in a different way. Now I don't know which one is the best, or even if what I did is correct at all. In one of my attempts I noticed something wrong with the sprite dimensioning a clipping so I added a check for the Retina and loaded the files according to that. And puff! Problem (appears to be) solved. So how do you handle Retina here?

Comment: One last thing, mine is a very simple animation with just to frame. This could be relevant. Unfortunately I don't have time right now to test with more frames :(

Comment: @EngineerGio, my apologies for a very delayed response. I didn't change anything in the code to handle retina graphics. I never had a problem getting retina to work. Glad to hear you found an alternative approach. I'd like to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain whether this is a 2.0 issue or not, but i notice you are using twice the chameleonDelay object in the same sequence. Is this really what you were trying to accomplish ie

delay,action,delay,delay,action,delay,delay,action .... etc.

try this to see if it works :

```
CCRepeatForever *chameleonRepeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:chameleonDelay, chameleonAction, nil]];
```

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. It was a combination of issues. I found that without adding it, for some reason, the actions wouldn't do what I intended which is go from frame 1, to frame 2, then quickly back to frame 1. Without the second delay, it stays on frame 2.  I'm sure it's the way I'm handling it, but the timing actually works out for what I want to accomplish anyways. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: to prevent the quick coming back to frame one, you may want to use [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:mouthAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]. But in any event, try to create another instance of CCDelayTime if you have two uses in the same sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't phrase it correctly. I DO want it to return to frame one. It's a mouth opening and closing. I tried restoreOriginalFrame:YES prior to ending up with this code and it didn't actually return to the first frame. No clue why. This coding worked exactly how I wanted it, so I just left it alone. Point taken about creating a second instance, I'll do that.

Comment: Oh, and just found this out: `restoreOriginalFrame:` has been deprecated in version 2.0. Not even an option anymore under `actionWithAnimation`.

Comment: The new code that I've posted in my edit resolves the having to duplicate the chameleonDelay action in the sequence. I also found that althought the statement `[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:mouthAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES];` is deprecated, you can put `mouthanim.restoreOriginalFrame = YES;` on it's own line and doesn't throw the deprecated warning. This didn't have the effect I expected, (none that I could see), so I just removed the statement.